# Not able to read data in from a text file.

Tags: c, xcode, io, text-files, scanf

Im having a problem finding out where to store my Text File which I want to read from. I stored it in the same directory as the executable file but it is still not reading the file in. After much digging and searching I have found that the problem has something to do with the "Derived Data" in Xcode. When I look for the source file , by right clicking on the main.c file and locating the file in finder I find that it is located within the Derived Data. Whenever I run this program it creates some derived data (which Xcode is supposed to do) but my .c file is stored within this derived data and when I try and store the text file in the same location the executable is located (the same place the .c file is located) I am not able to read in the file.

Suggestions?

Ideas?

Help..

```
#include <stdio.h>
    #include <unistd.h>
    extern int errno;
    int main (void){
        int term;
        long long StudentID;
        char lastname [16];
        char firstname[16];
        char subject[4];
        int catalog;
        char  section[4];
        char  filename [9];
        FILE *cfPtr;
        printf("Enter file name: ");
        scanf("%s",filename);
        /*
         char cwd [1024];
         if (getcwd(cwd, sizeof(cwd)) != NULL)
         fprintf(stdout, "Current working dir: %s\n", cwd);
         */
        system("pwd");
        if((cfPtr=fopen(filename,"r"))==0){
            //printf("%s jlk",strerror(errno));
            printf("File could not be opened\n");
        }
        else{
            printf("%-35s%-10s%-10s%-10s%-10s\n","Last Name, First Name","Term","ID","Course","Section");
            int i;
            for(i=0; i<75; i++){
                printf("-");
            }
            fscanf(cfPtr,"%d%lld%s%s%s%d%s",&term,&StudentID,lastname,firstname,subject,&catalog,section);
            while(!feof(cfPtr)){
                printf("%-35s%-10s%d%lld%-10s%-10s\n", lastname, firstname,term,StudentID,subject,section);
                fscanf(cfPtr,"%d%lld%s%s%s%d%s",&term,&StudentID,lastname,firstname,subject,&catalog,section);
            }

            fclose(cfPtr);

        }
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Off topic: should be `while(fscanf(...)==7)` to avoid the `while(!feof(...))` and to avoid repeating the `fscanf`.

Answer (score -1):

If you've set up a "Command Line Tool" project in Xcode, then you can set the working directory as follows. First click on the project name at the top of the Xcode window and select "Edit Scheme..."

[image]

Then select "Run Debug" on the left and change the "Working Directory" on the right.

[image]

The alternative is to download the command line tools (Preferences/Downloads). Then you can open a terminal window, and compile/run from the command line.